# Starting the Citrix Desktop Service once a specific user logs in

Tags: windows-7, services, active-directory, group-policy, citrix

I am working on a package to be released into an enterprise environment which needs to have the Citrix Desktop Service in a suspended state post deployment from CM.

In suspending the service post deployment, the workstation is not registered to any of the Citrix DDC servers (we have a cap on registration capacity).

When the user signs up for the Remote Access service online via Microsoft's FIM Portal, their username is moved into the Remote Access AD group. On user login, I'd like the Citrix Desktop Service to be automatically started when a user logs into the box, if they are part of that Remote Access AD group.

But to my knowledge, a service needs to start before the user logs in as Windows services operate on a machine level, so I'm left in quite a dilemma. How would I start the service once the correct user (who is part of the Remote Access AD group) logs in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Group Policy Preferences to target the compliant state of the user at logon.

ie. If users is "DOMAIN\UserInQuestion" and is member of "Remote Access AD Group" then start "Citrix Desktop Service", or a script that kicks it off.